# Easy way to enumerate class properties and then specify that property

Tags: c#, forms, dictionary, combobox, brush

I have a windows form and I want the user to specify the colour of a brush system.drawing.brush and then my app to consume this natively. There are loads of brush colours and I was wondering if it was possible to enumerate all the possible colour combinations?

I could then populate the combobox with them. THEN the second part would be to specify the brush property programmatically without having to do a lookup table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a list of Color names you can use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection):

```
Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);

PropertyInfo[] propInfoList = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);

var colorNames = propInfoList.Select(c => c.Name);
```

Use that list to populate your Combobox

Then, once user selects the Color, you can create a brush using the following:

```
var brushColor = Color.FromName(selectedColorFromCombo);

var brush = new SolidBrush(brushColor);
```

Comment: I had to change the datatype of colorNames to List<string> for the combobox to accept as a datasource but otherwise perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to declare enumerator like `public enum BrushColor{...}`, list all the colors there. Then, with this enumerator you could automatically populate combobox and then it also would be easy to determine the color based on user input (`switch` block).

You can get the list of colors using reflection:

```
Type brushes = typeof(Brushes);
var colorList = from color in brushes.GetProperties() select color.Name;
```

Combining this piece of code with logic mentioned at the beginning you can achieve your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I wanted to avoid having to do that if I could just work out how to set a property on the static brush class with a variable so I can pass to the DrawString class as there seems to be loads of info out there on how to enumerate the properties and put them into a nice list.

Comment: See edtied answer.